# How to use a pure TypeScript library as a dependency with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have 3 repos - `client`, `backend` and `interfaces`.

All are written in TypeScript. Client and backend repos compile into JavaScript during the build phase then deployed to server.

Last repo `interfaces` is not supposed to be compiled to anything, but just used as an npm dependency for both client and backend repos declaring how client and backend apps communicate with each other.

Before I introduced `interfaces` repo and added it as a dependency to both other repos, I used hardcoded messages types strings and all compiled just fine.

Now, with a purely TypeScript dependency, which is `interfaces`, I can inject types from it into `client` or `backend` repos code and see them connected properly.

But the problem is I cannot compile projects now because seems like something is not configured properly for this case in Webpack.

Here is the related piece of `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
            // exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
},
```

With this one I see an error while trying to build with webpack:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/myapp_interfaces/interfaces/ClientRequestPayload.ts
>
> Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (1:0)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

If I comment out `exclude: /node_modules/`, I see this:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/myapp_interfaces/index.ts
>
> Module build failed: Error: Typescript emitted no output for /myapp/myapp_backend/node_modules/myapp_interfaces/index.ts.
>
> You should not need to recompile .ts files in node_modules.
>
> Please contact the package author to advise them to use --declaration --outDir.

This interfaces code would work normally if it were in another folder of the project I suppose.

How do I get rid of this error and just import these into my code then compile?

Comment: Did you ever solve this, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue. I have same issue but my app isn't ejected so don't have webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude /node_modules/ from ts-loader isn't it expected that a .ts file in this folder is not imported properly ?

Comment: I tried both, kindly have a look at the error above.

Comment: Did you  run webpack with the webpack "--display-error-details" option ? Maybe you could grab more infos